# How to smoothen a jagged border of an image into a straight line?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image like this (thresholding, noise removal, etc. completed):

[image: Original Image]

My final output should be an image without any of the jagged edges, and smaller than the given image. By this, I mean to say that the only difference between the 2 images must be that in the new one, the jagged edges must be *removed*, and not the jagged edges *filled in*. Like so (the final image must be the region within the red border, the red border is shown only for explanation):

[image: Image showing how final border should be]

I was thinking of something along the lines of using Hough transforms, or of using dilations and then erosions, but nothing seems to be working (probably my fault, because I have not worked in too much detail with them before).

Note that the language I'd like t do this in is MATLAB.

There are 2 primary aims to this:

1. To get the edges themselves, using Hough transforms
2. So that the 'Extrema' property returns the desired pints when using regionprops, like so:

[image]

The question, in a more concise form:

1. How would I go about extracting this T in MATLAB, such that it does not have rugged edges, but the overall figure is not larger than the original, as shown in the second figure above? In other words, **what set of transformations (in MATLAB) would I use to smoothen the borders of the image *with as little of the area lost as little as possible* (but no area added) such that ruggedness disappears?**
2. Is there a more efficient way of extracting the corner (extrema) points as shown in figure 2 above without requiring to go through step 1?

EDIT:
A few more sample images:

NB: All images in consideration will be composed of rectangles approximately at 90 to each other, and no other figure. So smoothening an image with a curved edge, for example, would be beyond the scope of an answer to this question (or even, for that matter, a trapezium, although I think that smoothening 2 straight edges should be the same, irrespective of whether the edge has another parallel to it or not).

Here are a few more images, for reference:

[image: reference image 2]
[image: reference image 3, proof of my not-so-great GIMP skills]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question so that the question stands out more

Comment: Can you show some images for which you would like this algorithm to work. I think its relatively easy to write a code which works for this image, but difficult to generalize it, or do you care only about this image?

Comment: I further think that the problem isn't that easy even for this image because of your constraints, such that, the red line should lie inside the image. Anyway, I would suggest you to look at `bwtraceboundary`. It gives you a 2-element vector, so you trace the boundary and from their you get 2-element vector of boundary `([row col])`. Do a `diff` on that and find out the points where boundary changes direction. Once you get these points, you just to postprocess them to satisfy your constraint. You may not get entirely correct solution, but this is what I can think of as of now.

Comment: Do you require that your red line segments must be axis-aligned, or can they have any slope?

Comment: @beaker: No. They can have any slope, provided it fits the border from the inside as closely as possible.

Comment: I think rotating the image such that the endpoints joining of one of its edges form a straight line, would make the problem easy. For example, image of `A` can be rotated by ~ 50 degress in clockwise direction to make one of its lines straight.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar That would be easiest, I agree. But I'm not sure it would result in the maximal figure in the original image when rotated back (assuming that's a requirement).

Comment: @beaker Well, I am not thinking about maximal figure. If one of the edges are horizontal, then I think we get a horizontal line as a reference to work with. It may become easier to find points on that horizontal line where the edge starts changing direction. Of course, this is not a necessary step but just thought this may make things easier.

Comment: It strikes me that you might "lose" fewer pixels if you rotated the letter you have marked in red - yet you have drawn the red lines vertical and horizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer would satisfy your requirements. I'm putting it here because I think it's too long for a comment.

- since you want the final output to be smaller than the input image, erode the input image. You can pick an appropriate kernel size.
- perform a corner detection on this eroded image. This will give you all strong corners, but without any order
- trace the boundaries of the eroded image. This should give you an ordered list of boundary pixels
- now, with the help of these ordered boundary points you can order the corners that you found earlier
- filter corner points that form approximately 90 degrees of angle. You can do this considering each 3 ordered corner points (two green points and the red point in between in the image below. It's just for illustration, not corner points that I calculated. At the end of this operation, you have all red points in the image below which are at strong corners, in addition to other yellow and green corner points)
- now you can either find the equation of the line connecting 2 consecutive red points

or

- fit a least-squares-line to the points between (and including) each 2 consecutive red points
- since you did all this processing on a eroded image that is essentially smaller than the original image, you should get a smaller shape

[image]